# Jenkins - Setting up local Git repository for simple HelloWorld test

Tags: java, git, ubuntu, github, jenkins

If someone could give me some guidance on this it would be much appreciated! I've seen similar questions asked on here before but I can't seem to find an answer or get my head around the process.

What I want to do is set up a Git repository in which 2 Java files are located (`HelloWorld.java` and `HelloWorldErr.java` - `HelloWorldErr` is missing an `;` ). This is to test the Jenkins build and test system to see if it can successfully compile the `HelloWorld.java` file and run it, and also discover the error in `HelloWorldErr.java`. It's a pretty simple test but I'm having trouble getting it working.

After finally managing to set up the repository correctly, I now get an error saying:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

After scouting the internet for tutorials and/or anyone with similar problems I'm still looking for a solution. Even an explanation of the process would probably help me a lot.

My repository is located at `/var/lib/jenkins/repo/test_repo.git/` and the 2 Java files are in there. I left the branch specifier as `*/master` as I do not know what this does. I'm guessing this is what might be the problem?

In my *Execute shell* command I have:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

Obviously this means that it is not looking at `HelloWorldErr.java` but for now I just want the build to run successfully.

Sorry if I haven't explained myself very well as I'm new to Ubuntu, Jenkins and Git.

Once I get this working I am also planning to test running files through GitHub but I do not want to start on that before I can get the local Git working correctly.

Thanks in advance! Any insight on this is going to really help.

---- EDIT ----
If it helps here is the console output with branch set to `*/master`...

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HelloWorld/workspace
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url file:///var/lib/jenkins/repo/test_repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from file:///var/lib/jenkins/repo/test_repo.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress file:///var/lib/jenkins/repo/test_repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
> git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE`
```

And here is the output when I leave branch blank...

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HelloWorld/workspace
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url file:///var/lib/jenkins/repo/test_repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from file:///var/lib/jenkins/repo/test_repo.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress file:///var/lib/jenkins/repo/test_repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen 0 remote branches
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Did you actually add and commit those files in your Git repository?

Comment: After initially having errors with my git repository, I made a new one at `/var/lib/jenkins/repo/test_repo.git/` and moved the files there using `sudo mv HelloWorld.java /var/lib/jenkins/repo/test_repo.git/`

Comment: How would I go about committing the files?

Comment: `git add . && git commit -m "my shiny commit message"`

Comment: I'm a complete novice with Ubuntu/Linux/Bash so forgive me for not quite understanding. Do I need to navigate to my test_repo.git folder to run this command? Does the content of the commit message matter?

I get the message `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: Check if you have anything to add and commit with `git status` Yes, you must stand in your git repo to do this.

Comment: Thanks Ola, unfortunately I get the error message `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: Right, I went up a directory and used git status and got this `nothing added to commit but tracked files present (use "git add" to track)`

Comment: I think you start learning how Git works

Comment: OMG! https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow - Please read how GIT works! you need to go into your repository folder to run git commands. it is the folder with the .git folder inside. Which GIT server you're using? Github? Bitbucket\Stash?